# How can i update and insert by one Request

Tags: laravel

I have two table. one is allocation_details table and another is stock_deatails table.

allocation_details table

[image]

stock_deatails

[image]

one `allocation_id` have multiple `product_id`. this `product_id` would match with the `stock_details` table column `product_id`.

Now when i insert the `allocation_id`, this `allocation_id` of `product_id` will match the `stock_details` table column `product_id` and update the unit of ``` stock_details`` table column ``` unit`.

If don't match `allocation_id` of `product_id` with the **stock_details** table column `product_id` it will create or insert new row in `stock_details` table. How can i do that.

My controller code is:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $voucher = $request->input('voucherNo');

        $allocations = AllocationDetail::where('allocation_id', '=', $voucher)->get();

 
            foreach ($allocations as $allocation) {
                $plus = StockDetails::all()
                    ->where('product_id', '=', $allocation['product_id'])
                    ->where('showroom_id', '=', $allocation['showroom_id'])
                    ->first();

                $plus->increment('unit', $allocation['unit']);
                
            }



    }
```

Here is AllocationDetail model code

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AllocationDetail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'allocation_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'allocation_id', 'showroom_id', 'product_id', 'unit'
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
    public function showroom()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Showroom::class);
    }

    
}
```

Here is ShowroomStock model code

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ShowroomStock extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

`Laravel` has `firstOrCreate()`, which finds a model or creates a new one. Also avoid using all as this should be and can be done as a query.

```
StockDetails::where('product_id', '=', $allocation['product_id'])
    ->where('showroom_id', '=', $allocation['showroom_id'])
    ->firstOrCreate([
        'product_id' => $allocation['product_id'],
        'showroom_id' => $allocation['showroom_id'],
        // fill other columns needed
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. but incrementing is not working( I mean when same product_id will match increment opertion is not working)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. but incrementing is not working( I mean when same product_id will match increment opertion is  working but next when i insert a allocation_id it's will not incrementing of same product_id. it will create again a row of same product_id)

Comment: What do you mean by that? increment should work just as fine

Comment: yes. problem solved. Thanks for your reply and your help.

Comment: If the answer helped please accept it as the answer or if you found out yourself, answer the question your self so if people seeing this question can know what worked.

Answer (score 0):

I make my database table **stock_details** column **unit** default zero. so unit increment perfectly.

```
 $allocations = AllocationDetail::where('allocation_id', '=', $voucher)->get();


        foreach ($allocations as $allocation) {
            $plus = StockDetails::all()
                ->where('product_id', '=', $allocation['product_id'])
                ->where('showroom_id', '=', $allocation['showroom_id'])
               ->firstOrCreate([
        'product_id' => $allocation['product_id'],
        'showroom_id' => $allocation['showroom_id'],
       //'unit' => $allocations[0]['unit'],
        'transfer' => 0,
        'sold' => 0,
    ]);
       if($plus){
            $plus->increment('unit', $allocation['unit']);
           } 
        }    
}
```